# Setting the cron job to reset the python program after it is terminated

Tags: web-scraping, cron, cron-task

I want to set a cron job in ubuntu with this job

I have a python webscraping program which needs to be scrapped continuously after the program is terminated. In other words the flow is like this

```
If program is terminated, set the cron job again (until infinity)
```

Can this be done?

thanks

Comment: Yes it can be done. Add a simple bash script in cron that will check if the program is running and start it if it wasn't.

Comment: Can you please write it from me? I am very beginner in bash. The program i want to run is python.py